# Css Media Queries layout breaks on wrong width

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm stuck on this problem, I'm working with a media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 527px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    body {background-color:green}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 526px) {
    body {background-color:red}
        }
```

If I understand it correctly anything below 526px will display the colour red
I also have this jquery which displays the browser width:

```
 <script>
        $(window).resize(function () {

            $(window).height();
            $(window).width(); 
            $(".width-value2").text($(window).width());
        });
    </script>
```

And in the head of page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But when the width hits 510px according to jquery it changes to green,17px before its supposed to.

Is the jquery displaying the wrong width, if so how do I display the correct width.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 17px is a scrollbar width.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without a JSFiddle but it is possible that you are not accounting for the scroll bar or some other browser element.

Comment: Thanks, been on this for hours and its was something as simple as that, I need a rest :-(

Answer (score 2):

This is because of scrollbar (17 px).

**Note**, that in chrome browser one scrollbar width, in firefox another, in ie another etc...

Use [mqGenie](https://github.com/stowball/mqGenie) tool fix this. Also, it eliminates scrollbar difference in different browsers (read note). [Demo](http://stowball.github.io/mqGenie/)

Or, if you don't want mqGenie find something same. Now you know what was the reason of the problem.